# What are the six OT quotes in the NT, which are not from the Septuagint?

Tags: septuagint

What are the six OT quotes in the NT, which are not from the Septuagint? I was aware that some of them were not, but it's surprising to learn (see below) that there are only six of them. And, an associated question (which may be a duplicate, sorry) is, where might I find a list of all these 200 OT quotes in the NT?

> “The Septuagint was a good strong anchor for theologians and scholars to determine, what the Bible was really like in apostolic times” the Rev. Dr. Gordon Walker, an emeritus priest at St. Ignatius Antiochian Orthodox Church in Madison, Tenn. said in a telephone interview. “In the New Testament, all but six of the Old Testament quotes that were used, came from the Septuagint.” New Testament writers quoted Scripture more than 200 times, he said. The other six references were taken from Aramaic and Hebrew texts available at the time. (Vicksburg Post - Vicksburg,
>    MS)

Note: Looking among the many related posts, I found this information from a participant called "Zenon." Below is my attempt to link you to the site where Zenon says "This website" ... hopefully, this works

> http://www.kalvesmaki.com/LXX/NTChart.htm
>
> This website provides an exhaustive list of instances where the NT quotes the OT. It gives the passages side-by-side from the NT, the Septuagint, and the Masoretic. Some are virtually identical between the texts; others vary rather significantly.

Comment: Interesting. Since the site you linked to that I linked to doesn’t mention these passages supposedly not found in the Septuagint, either that website or Rev. Dr. Gordon Walker has some faulty information. Another possibility is that the website with the chart simply excludes these because it doesn’t consider them OT references unless they appear in the Septuagint. I’ve always been told that the Jewish people in Jesus’s time had nothing but the Septuagint, so I wonder if they would’ve had access to any inspired texts outside the Septuagint.

Comment: A quick search of the Vicksburg Post website finds no mention of a Gordon Walker. Might you be able to provide the full article or a link to it to provide some context? It might be worth attempting to contact Dr. Walker.

Comment: https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/greek-texts/septuagint/default.asp?pg=4

Found the quote in the Introduction, page 4, of this site for the Septuagint.

https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/greek-texts/septuagint/default.asp

Comment: @zenon, It is my understanding that Jews in Israel would have used the Hebrew version. Jews in other countries spoke Greek, so would have used the Septuagint. By the time  the Gospel books were written, the church was primarily gentile, so at the Septuagint became the standard.

Comment: @disciple But they didn’t speak Hebrew, they spoke Aramaic. They would’ve used the Septuagint seeing as everyone in that time spoke Greek as well as their native tongue, kind of like English is today.

Comment: Hebrew and Aramaic are very similar. The average Jew would have depended on someone else to read the scripture. That might have been a written translation (targum), but more likely it would be read in Hebrew and explained in Aramaic. We do know that the Jewish community disowned the Septuagint by the early 2nd Century, but that might have been only because the Christians used it. I seriously doubt if the average person knew more than a crude form of Greek.

Answer (score 1):

Protestant authors Archer and Chirichigno list 340 places where the New Testament cites the Septuagint but only 33 places where it cites from the Masoretic Text rather than the Septuagint (G. Archer and G. C. Chirichigno, Old Testament Quotations in the New Testament: A Complete Survey, 25-32). 
https://www.catholic.com/qa/in-which-passages-does-jesus-quote-the-septuagint-and-where-does-the-new-testament-allude-to-the